# If $L_1 \cup L_2 \in RE$ does it implicate that at least one of them is also in RE?

Tags: regular-languages, automata

This was one of my exam questions and the answer is apparently no.

Can someone explain why because I don't understand.

Comment: @Jut, please do not use the comments here to advertise one of your other posts.  That is not an appropriate use of comments.

Answer (score 1):

There exist languages which are **Non-RE** and their complement is also **Non-RE**, let $L$ be such a language we can say that

$L \cup L^{c} = \Sigma^{*}$

Here both languages are **Non-RE** but their union is $\Sigma^{*}$ which is regular as well as **RE** also.